# Texture paint not painting properly

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, texture-paint-mode

I am having an issue with Texture paint. For some reason, when i am in any other tab, be it layout or modelling, my texture painting does not look right. It looks like this:
[image]

Then when i go to the Texture Paint tab, it paints fine. I checked the UVs many times and it looks fine, but i have no idea what is going on. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I am trying to paint over a wood texture that i have applied, and i am trying to make a gradient out of it with texture paint.

Comment: forgot to add the file :https://www.mediafire.com/file/3i5tawuv90hgshk/John%2527s_Other_Guitar.blend/file

Answer (score 0):

The *Solid* mode will give a basic preview of your image texture, but it won't take your *Shader Editor* setup into account. Here in your *Mapping* node you have rotated your texture 90° on Z, if you want to see your material as it is really set, switch to *Material* preview:

[image]

If you want to paint over this wood texture, don't paint directly on the image, instead use a *Color > Color Mix* node to mix the wood and a transparent image you will paint on, use the *Alpha* output as factor in the *Color Mix*:

[image]

Comment: Incredible, i cannot believe i missed that, thank you so much! Btw, do you know of a way to erase the paint i have made? I cant find an eraser and using alpha erase just erases my image.
Thank you

Comment: You can't unpaint (except with some Ctrl Z), you need to reload the original wood texture, if you want to paint over this wood texture, don't paint directly on the image, instead use a Color > Color Mix node to mix the wood and a transparent image you will paint on

Comment: I see. I may be doing something wrong, but it is not working for me. The guitar just turns black and nothing shows up.

Comment: please share your new file

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/cpvg492t61iyt91/John's+Other+Guitar.blend/file

Comment: Seem my edit.............

Comment: I see, thank you. I was doing it right, but the issue i have is for some reason nothing shows up when i paint. I made a transparent image (i think) through Blender, but nothing happens

Comment: Nevermind, i had it to mulitply. It only works in Mix mode?